# How to make an object not able to pass through an object? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The title doesn't really explain much so ill expand more. I'm making a 2D game where you move a mouse to help you do stuff. I am using a fake mouse which is controlled by your mouse. And I want to make it so the mouse can't just move through walls. I've tried adding rigid bodies but the mouse still passes through it, or the wall just gets pushed by the mouse. (The mouse has a RigidBody2D script on it and a polygon collider 2D and the wall has a box collider 2D, and a RigidBody 2D) Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you provide the movement script of the mouse?

Comment: If both have what you say, mouse has rigidbody + 2d-collider and walls have 2d-collider then it should work. A few things to note: it will only work if you move by physics (ie not teleporting each frame) and don't move it too fast (change rigidbody collision setting to "continous" if so).

Comment: @FredrikSchön I think you might have got it, I am not moving the mouse using physics, I am teleporting it every frame. I don't know why I didn't think of that. I'll try it now!

Comment: @FredrikSchön Thanks a lot, I have no idea how I didn't think about that.

Comment: If you have a rigidbody and colliders then it’s down to how you move it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both have what you say, mouse has rigidbody + 2d-collider and walls have 2d-collider then it should work. A few things to note: it will only work if you move by physics (ie not teleporting each frame) and don't move it too fast (change rigidbody collision setting to "continous" if so). – Fredrik Schön

This solved it for me, Thanks